# How to make min-width in percentage work in in IE7?

Tags: css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

How to make {min-width:100%} work in in IE7? working fine in IE8+ and other browsers.

I'm using a dropdown menu where width of dropdown should depend on longest text in dropdown but not less then the parent's link width. So I added min-width:100% to dropdown. But it's working for other browsers but not for IE7.

How I can make it work?

**Demo is here to fork and play with it. Check this in IE7** http://codepen.io/jitendravyas/pen/AheDs

Comment: Can't say for sure without seeing the code. Are you setting the size of the parent/parent's parent/etc explicitly?

Comment: @vdbuilder No there is not fixed width for parent because text of parent can also be flexible

Comment: It's been a while since I needed to think about getting around it but IE7- was a little ****** about setting width of element's tree to get min/max/width to work properly. Easiest thing to do is get out js and do it yourself :(

Comment: @vdbuilder I have added demo to my question. see dropdown on hover in IE7 to know the problem

Comment: you should consider my answer because the answer should not be an old  story about 1001 solutions to 1001 compatibility problems in one browser, it should be one solution to 1001 compatibility problems in all browsers.

Comment: Did any of the answers provided help you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS - How to make IE7 respect min-width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068967/css-how-to-make-ie7-respect-min-width)

Answer (score 5):

Please check [This](http://blog.throbs.net/2006/11/17/IE7+And+MinWidth+.aspx) i think its exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Try Modernizr, it makes a lot of things possible in older/less compatible browsers without a lot of trouble. Try the development version to see if it can help you and compose your own production version targeting your specific needs to minimize the size (and speed) of the javascript library.

> Modernizr is a JavaScript library that detects HTML5 and CSS3 features
>   in the user’s browser.

Comment: I dropped the modernizr code in your codepen and it works: http://codepen.io/jitendravyas/full/AheDs

Comment: I used https://spoon.net/browsers for a quick and free virtual IE7 (has also ie6, multiple other browsers and more - https://spoon.net/apps)

Answer (score 2):

IE7 does not function like the other browsers in this manner. It needs an explicit `width` on the parent element. Your *current code* gives it a `width` here:

```
.site-nav .flyout-content{
    border:1px solid #e4e4e3;
    /*  width:100%;*/
    height:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    *width:170px;  <-------------- THIS IS PICKED UP BY IE7
    box-shadow: 8px 6px 10px rgba(65, 65, 65, 0.45);
}
```

If you know the `width` of your widest element, you could change that number there to a wider amount, which "works" as [**this fiddle demonstrates**](http://jsfiddle.net/nvzmq/7/) (Note: the CodePen example was not working for me in IE7 mode, so I moved the code to jsfiddle.net). However, it may be better for you to implement some javascript workaround for IE7 similar to [**the solution in this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173444/how-can-one-make-a-containers-child-divs-match-the-width-of-the-largest-child-i) (which basically was asking the same thing as you are).

Answer (score 1):

check [CSS Compatibility and Internet Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28VS.85%29.aspx). Make sure you have an appropriate doc type and toy are not in Quirks mode by looking in the developer tools at the Document Mode.

[check IE7 and minWidth](http://blog.throbs.net/2006/11/17/IE7+And+MinWidth+.aspx)

Comment: can you help how to use this script here http://codepen.io/jitendravyas/pen/pzJuK

Answer (score 1):

ie9.js claims to add support for min-width, and you can add it to your source to test with:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

You can read more about the ie7.js project (including ie9.js) at http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/.

Please keep in mind, some other javascript libraries, such as css3 pie will not work with ie9.js.