# DIV is not expanding in IE7, IE8 and IE9

Tags: html, css

I am using four `DIV`s: container, header, content and footer.

Based on the text or images the content `DIV` is expanded but the header and footer `div` do not expand in IE7, IE8 and IE9 but works fine in Firefox, IE10 and IE11.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
<style>
body {
    height:100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-block;
}

#header {
    top:0px;
    height:75px;
    width:100%;
}

#container {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#content {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

#footer {
    top:5px;
    bottom:0px;
    height:45px;
    width:100%;
}
</style>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does he need to expand vertical or horizontal? because the footer and header have a fixed height of 45pc and 75px.

Comment: i need to expand horizontal

Comment: Than I don't understand why it is not working because the width is `100%` so it should work

Comment: @  Vinc199789.. i dont know why header and footer width is not expanded when the content div expand.

Answer (score 3):

You have a fixed value on `footer` and `header`

```
#footer
{
    top:5px;
    bottom:0px;
    /*height:45px;*/
    width:100%;
}
#header
{
    top:0px;
    /*height:75px;*/
    width:100%;
}
```

When it has fixed value, the element won't expand. The `min-height` could be a simple solution but a browser that doesn't support `CSS2.0` won't process it right and could give you an unexpected result.

---

**ANSWER UPDATED...**

I'm giving you an answer that you might have expected. I still don't know what you are trying to achieve, what kind of layout do you need, and etc. But with a wild guess, I tweaked this code. It's going to be the exact answer for you if what you wanted was making `header` and `footer` responsive to the `content` div.

```css
body {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding:0;
}

#header {
  top:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:75px;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#eaeaea;
}

#content {
  display:table;
  padding:75px 0 45px;
  height:150px;
  position:relative;
}

#footer {
  bottom:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:45px;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#1d1d1d;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>

  <div id="content">
            
            <h3>Expanding as you expected....</h3>
            <h5>
                * Try remove these h3 and h5 element. <br/>
              the result will be nothing on your screen because no dimension is given to content div.
            </h5>
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Try and see above code result and test how it expands as the `content` div gets smaller or bigger.

Comment: thank you for your reply.....my exact problem is the width of header and footer was not expanded dynamically when expanding content div.

Comment: @VenkatRaj Was it? if you wanted your `header` and `footer` to start from 0px to Npx as the expansion of your `content`, why did you put `width:100%` at the first place? I want to help you but I don't picture what kind of layout you are thinking of.

Comment: @VenkatRaj  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043393/how-to-make-min-width-in-percentage-work-in-in-ie7 . Take a look to that link and special to the first answer

Comment: @VenkatRaj Give me your full html code including the declaration of doctype.

Answer (score 0):

**style.css**

```
      body
        {
            height:100%;
            margin-left: 0;
            margin-top: 0;
            padding:0;
            width:100%;
            position: relative;
            display:inline-block;
        }
        .header
        {
            top:0px;
            height:75px;
            width:100%;
        }
        .container
        {
            display:table;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
        }
        .content
        {
            width:100%;
            height:auto;
        }
        .footer
        {
            top:5px;
            bottom:0px;
            height:45px;
            width:100%;
        }

**index.xhtml**


   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
                xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile"
    >
<f:view>
 <h:head>
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"></meta>
 </h:head>
 <h:body>
  <div class="container"> 

   <div class="header" class="ui-layout-unit-header ui-widget-header">    
        <ui:include src="${ModuleGenerator.headerPageh}" />
   </div>

   <div class="content" class="ui-panel-content ui-widget-content">
        <ui:include src="/pages/system/homeContent.xhtml"/>
   </div>  

   <div class="footer" class="ui-layout-unit-footer ui-widget-header">
        <ui:include src="${ModuleGenerator.headerPageh}" />
   </div>

</div>

  </h:body>
  </f:view>
</ui:composition>
```

I have posted my full code of my layout...i hope it will okey for you to undestand yourself and reply.

this page working fine in IE10,IE11 and firefox but not works in IE6,IE7 and IE8.

what i am trying to achieve is? when the content(width) of div is expand  dynamically the header and footer div(width) also expand based on content(width).

When we scroll down the page on browser then that page need to get centre alignment.

i am the beginner.

if you need further details post me.i will reply.